# Swift: iterate a dictionary of arrays without copying anything

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a dictionary like `[String:[MyClass]]` and I want to access each value in each array in the dictionary, **but without any copying**.

Can I do this with `for..in`? Or maybe the `forEach` method does the job?

Comment: in which part of _"to access each value"_ do you think you'd copy _anything_...?

Comment: Do neither `for (key, array) in dict` or `for value in array` copy the value? Are Swift's copy-by-value semantics only in play when using `let` or `var`?

Comment: There will always be copying (that's the nature of values; that would be true no matter what the type, and in fact is true in every language that has any kind of values). But it's unclear what problem you're trying to address. The copying will be minimal here. If you're iterating over a dictionary, use `for…in`.

Comment: So even if the arrays inside my dictionary have hundreds of items, the copying by the `for..in` loop wouldn't impact performance enough to matter?

Comment: Certainly not. It's not going to copy the entire array contents, and `for...in` won't even create a copy of the array pointers. Write the code naturally. Then profile.

Comment: Note that if you start modifying those arrays, you definitely *can* run into complex performance problems due to Swift copying, but this isn't that case.

Comment: Ah I see, so Swift arrays are not copied until mutation, basically?

Comment: Sort of. It's actually more complicated than that. The problem is when you say "without any copying." There is almost nothing you can do that has no copying. "x = y + 7" involves copying. `x = array.count` involves copying. The question is how much you're copying.

Comment: Again, write it naturally, then profile. Don't start by trying to second-guess it. Swift performance is extremely complicated and often non-intuitive.

Comment: The one thing you should not be asking is "should I use `for...in` here or `forEach` (the answer is `for...in`). If you had a problem, the question you should ask is "should I replace `[String:[MyClass]]` with a different data structure that meets my needs better?"

Comment: Yep, makes sense. The original question stemmed from a misunderstanding of when copying comes into play, and assuming there was a way to treat Swift arrays as reference for purpose of iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate normally with `for..in` and not worry about the value copying mechanics. If you are interested in what's happening under the hood, look up *copy-on-write* behaviour, which Swift arrays adopt.

The gist of it is: A copy of the array (or any other data structure that implements copy-on-write) will only be created in memory when you modify that array. If it doesn't mutate, the two array instances will still use the same underlying memory.